# How to read Sequence pipe delimeted data format in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have input data format:

1|0.12202410112390383|9ac56489-5580-4057-9ec3-3d118d9dad01|test

saved as sequence file.

I would like to read this file, convert it to text format and use only two fields for future processing. So my code should looks like:

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar

DEFINE SequenceFileLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader();

AA = load '/user/hdfs/input/*' using SequenceFileLoader() as (id:chararray, propability:chararray, userId:chararray, text:chararray);

AA = foreach AA generate userId, text;

store AA into '/output8' using PigStorage();
```

But on output I see that AA contains pipe delimited format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sequencefiles are key-value pairs, and there's no real delimiter.  I assume that in this case the values are the pipe-delimited strings; in that case you'll have to use [tokenize](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#tokenize) to parse the string and then select items from the bag by index.

Comment: you are right, the output is pipe-delimited strings. After tokenisation B = FOREACH AA GENERATE TOKENIZE(body,'|'); how can I select bag by index and assign it to my variables userId and text?

Comment: Dealing with the bag output from tokenize ends up being a bit of a pain; easier might be 
`AA = LOAD .... AS (data:chararray);
tokens = FOREACH AA GENERATE strsplit(data,'|',8);
fields = FOREACH tokens GENERATE $0.$5 AS userID, $0.$7 AS text; store fields....`